# How does listeners in Provider work in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am using Provider package to work with data from different locations. For this question, I have created a sample project which consists of a Welcome Screen which shows a Login button, upon click, it redirects to Login Screen where one would have login text field but for now, I have placed a button which on click calls the login function and that login function notifies the listeners. I also have a logout function and boolean value which keeps track of the logged in status.

These functions and values reside in a file called `auth.provider.dart` in providers directory in lib folder.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  var _loggedIn = false;

  bool get loggedIn => _loggedIn;

  void loginUser() {
    _loggedIn = true;
    print('Logged in');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void logout() {
    _loggedIn = false;
    print('Logged out');
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I am providing the provider in main.dart and also using Consumer:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Auth>(
      create: (_) => Auth(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: Consumer<Auth>(
          builder: (_, auth, __) {
            print('main.dart logged in: ${auth.loggedIn}');
            if(auth.loggedIn) return HomeScreen();
            return WelcomeScreen();
          },
        ),
        routes: {
          LoginScreen.routeName: (ctx) => LoginScreen(),
          HomeScreen.routeName: (ctx) => HomeScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the above file, I simply check whether `loggedIn` is true or not. If it is not then show the welcome screen so the user can login but if the user is logged in then directly show the home screen. Have also put a print statement in Consumer's builder so it prints the status whenever it gets notified of any changes in auth data. This runs once when the app starts and never again.

There is not much in the login screen, just a scaffold and a login button which calls the login function.

```
RaisedButton(
    child: Text('Click to Login'),
    onPressed: () {
      Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).loginUser();
    },
),
```

Now on login button click, it sets the `loggedIn` boolean to true and notifies the listener which should be Consumer but Consumer in main.dart is never notified of it. It does not trigger the change, there is a condition which checks if logged in is true then show home screen but screen does not change at all. One has to manually use `Navigator` to move to home screen and on home screen there is a logout button which simply sets `loggedIn` to false, once that happens it should notify the Consumer but it once again doesn't.

Which now brings me to the question: How does listeners in Provider work? When does it notify the listeners for changes? Will it not notify if the changes occur more than a level down like in the above example, Consumer is in main.dart and the changes occur 2 levels down `main.dart > WelcomeScreen > LoginScreen`. How to let the Consumer in `main.dart` know that the underlying data it is using has changed?

*If you want to quickly get started with the above example, [here](https://github.com/gegobyte/provider-demo) is the repository link.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through your github code.

**With pushReplacementNamed to go to login screen**

> Initially->main.dart->welcomeScreen->(on-clicking-loginbtn)->LoginScreen

Here,

1)Consumer is not listening(because your initial main.dart screen is replaced by login page and doesnt exist on a page currently to listen)

2)There is no navigator to go back(because page is replaced not in a stack)

**With pushNamed to go to login screen**

> Initially->main.dart->welcomeScreen->(on-clicking-loginbtn)->LoginScreen

Here,

1)Consumer is listening(because your initial main.dart screen is not replaced and exist on a page currently.But you are not seeing the changes because you have covered your main intial page with login screen above in the stack )

2)There is navigator to go back to HomeScreen(Now you can go back to see changes using back arrow)

> **Conclusion** Page will not able to listen to changed Provider Value if the page is replaced by other page. It should be there in a screen listening.

**Pattern that can be used**

**main.dart(home argument)**

```
home: Consumer<Auth>(
          builder: (_, auth, __) {
            print('main.dart logged in: ${auth.loggedIn}');
            if(auth.loggedIn) return HomeScreen();
            return WelcomeScreen();
          },
        )
```

**WelcomeScreen(login code)**

```
 RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Login'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(LoginScreen.routeName),
            )
```

**LoginScreen(login button)**

```
RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Click to Login'),
          onPressed: () {
            Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).loginUser();
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/');
          },
        )
```

**HomeScreen(signout btn)**

```
RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Logout'),
         onPressed: () {
            Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).logout();
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/');
          }
```

Comment: Won't `pushNamed` create infinite pages on stack as in a production app, login page will have the option to go to signup page as well as forgot password page and all those pages will be interlinked. To prevent such a scenario, I used `pushReplacementNamed`

Comment: Yes you are right. I am not referring you to use pushNamed. I am just explaining different scenerios.There is no use of using provider for this case.You can simply use Navigation. Provider are used when you want some global state in multiple widgets.

Comment: I have send pull-request to your repo. You can look into it

Comment: The reason for using Provider is that I can get user data in any page after login. For example - to store or read something in Firestore, I would need access to currently logged in user. If I don't use Provider in `main.dart`, how would I know whether the user is logged in or not and to show the correct screen accordingly? So for the sake of consistency, I am using Provider as I will have to use it anyway in other screens.

Comment: I have updated my answer. It stores login info in a provider and navigation is done based on the provider value. Hope it solves your problem. I will provide pull request (if you need full code)

Comment: I also changed `pushReplacementNamed` to `pushNamed` so that `main.dart` page remains in the stack but still the redirect to home screen isn't happening automatically. I have pushed the latest commit.

Comment: Redirect to home screen is happening automatically in my latest code(in my updated answer as well as in github)

Comment: Can you merge a pull request?

Comment: I've seen your pull request. You've used Navigator to change screens which will work. I am trying to make it work without Navigator by doing what you had originally said, i.e using `pushNamed` but it isn't working for me.

Comment: I am using Navigator but it is navigating to main screen which then see the provider value to confirm if user is logged-in or not and then corresponding correct page is displayed.You can see my latest code on https://github.com/dipesh429/provider-demo

Comment: You are using `pushReplacementNamed` in your latest code which I am not using for the moment as I am looking to understand how Consumer work. So I am using `pushNamed` so the login screen is also on stack and the consumer can rebuild automatically but it is not changing the screen even if the logged in status changes.

Comment: I have explained above that using pushNamed allows the consumer to listen. But since you have login screen above main screen.You are not seeing the changes below the page. But if you go back to stack by pressing back button,you can see you are already redirected to home screen.